# Error ORA-04043: object SYS_PLSQL_XXXX does not exist while adding new columns to the existing table

Tags: oracle

Can any one tell me why I'm getting ORA-04043: object SYS_PLSQL_XXXXX error while I'm trying to Alter  an exiting table to add new columns.

I did not get this error when I altered the same table last week.

thanks

Comment: It might be helpful to edit your question to include the complete DDL for the table as it is now (via `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`), the exact command you're trying to run, the full error stack you get, and if possible the command you ran last week. All as formatted text please, not images.

Comment: This is the command that I ran today and last week tooalter table1
add ( 
col1   VARCHAR2(3),
col2 VARCHAR2(3));